# Read jubula h2 db file and populate the test suite along with test cases

Tags: jubula

I am new to Eclipse Jubula. Can the following points be performed on local h2 DB created by jubula?:

1) Get all the test suite along with test cases from the DB.

2) Set active/inactive to the test case and update it to DB again.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of doing this that is documented or recommended.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was wondering of creating a driver for jubula which would display all the test suites along with test cases and trigger run. But now would have to change my approach.

Comment: I am not sure how correct my process for reading the h2 db. This is how I have achieved the above:
 1. Convert the db to .xml using import (provided by Jubula)
 2. Read the .xml and find the tag for scenario and the get all names and status
Do any modification to activate/deactivate if needed. Save and export back to Jubula